# How to use Holo style for some views if application theme is Material?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have an Android application where app theme defined in `styles.xml` like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
</style>
```

(I know that it requires API level 21)

But I want to use some old styles from `Theme` or `Theme.Holo` for some views.

I test it on Nexus 4 with Android 5.1 API 22.

It works for progress bar:

```
    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
```

In this case I see 3 progressBars with different styles, but it doesn't work for EditText:

```
    <EditText
        style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="test test"
        />

    <EditText
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="test test"
        />

    <EditText
        style="@style/CustomEditText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="test test"
        />
```

where `CustomEditText` is:

```
<style name="CustomEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText">
</style>
```

But all this EditText in Material theme.

How to show `EditText` with `Holo` theme if main theme is `Material`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `android:theme` attribute with `Theme.Holo`.

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="test test" />
```